# SceneLoader turning off Directional Lights

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene, directional-light

I made a simple scene loader scene, but whenever it loads a level my directional lights don't seem to load in. It only happens when the scene is loaded with the Scene Loader, not when opened directly in the editor.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject loadingImage;
    public GameObject removeUI;

    public void LoadScene(int level)
    {
        Application.LoadLevelAsync(level);
        loadingImage.SetActive (true);
        removeUI.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

`loadingImage` is an image on a canvas that says "Loading..."

`removeUI` is the text on the level and the buttons that trigger `LoadScene()`, passing in level from the scene builder level order.